# in a chrome extension can a background page talk to a page_action popup

Tags: popup, google-chrome-extension, message-passing

It is possible for a content script to talk to the background page using

```
chrome.extension.sendRequest
```

It is possible for the background page to talk to the content script using

```
chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab) {
  chrome.tabs.sendRequest(tab.id, {}, function(response) {
      // do something with response here
  })
})
```

It is possible for a page_action popup to talk to the background page using

```
chrome.extension.sendRequest
```

So, is there a way for the background page to talk to the popup?

The use case is one where

- the popup is open and wants to get some information from the page
- so it sends a request to the background page
- the background page now sends a request to the content script
- and the content script sends a response back to the background page.
- So now the background script needs to send this to the popup !!

  How does that happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can, using `chrome.extension.sendRequest`, as long as popup remains open.

But looking at your workflow, why not just skip background page and send request to a content script directly from a popup? Then you can just use `sendResponse()` to return the data back to popup.

Comment: /facepalm you are right the popup can talk directly to the content script after getting the selected tab. Also, for those needing the background to talk back to the popup, it occurred to me that once the popup sends the request, the background can keep the connection alive whilst it taks to the content script and return the response after it gets the result.

Comment: Also, don't forget that the background page can always be accessed from any of your extension's pages (except for content scripts) using [chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage()](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/extension.html#method-getBackgroundPage).